# Truncate NUL bytes off a file

Tags: file, bash

I have about 500 files with trailing NUL bytes, maybe produced with

```
truncate -s 8M <file>
```

How can I cut off the zeroes?

Comment: do you mean the ASCII character zero (`0`), or NUL bytes?  the latter sounds more like what you might get from truncating a (binary) file.

Comment: do the files have NUL bytes _because_ you used `truncate`, which pads shorter files to the requested size?  maybe the real answer is to not use it on files smaller than 8M  :)

Comment: @Eevee Nope, I downloaded those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This perl script should do it:

```
for f in *; do
    perl -e '$/=undef;$_=<>;s|\0+$||;print;' < $f > $f_fixed
done
```

This will keep all NULs within the file, remove any at the end, and save the result into `<original filename>_fixed`.

Script explanation:  `$/=undef` tells perl to operate on the whole file rather than splitting it into lines; `$_=<>` loads the file; `s|\0+||` removes any string of NULs at the end of the loaded file 'string'; and `print` outputs the result.  The rest is standard Bash file redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a "text" file and not a "binary" file, you can simply do

```sh
strings a.txt > b.txt
```

[**ref**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings)

Answer (score 0):

Use [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29):

```
cat $input_file | tr -d '\0' > $output_file
```

Note that `$input_file` and `$output_file` must be different

Comment: That also deletes NUL bytes which are not at the end of the file.

Comment: Ahh, good point, I assumed (wrongly) that these were text files.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @Eevee, you can actually avoid truncating those files below 8M. Using the following condition in your loop and the fact that `truncate` will assume bytes as default if you don't append any suffix to the size parameter, this won't pad the files below 8M:

```bsh
for file in $(ls -c1 directory); do
    # ... 

    SIZE=$(stat -c%s $file)
    LIMIT=$((8 * 1024 * 1024))
    if [ "$SIZE" -lt "$LIMIT" ]; then
        truncate -s $SIZE $file
    else 
        truncate -s 8M $file
    fi

    # ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really any Unix tool for this particular case.  Here's a Python (3) script:

```
import sys

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(contents.rstrip(b'\0'))
```

Run as:

```
python retruncate.py file1 file2 files* etc...
```